# empty() returns true if a zero float value was passed as string

Tags: php, comparison, php-7, string-comparison, php-8

MySQL with PHP can sometimes be annoying when decimals are returned as strings like with MYSQL functions. Is there a function to check if a variable is any of these in one?

null, (bool)false, (int)0, (float)0.00, (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", or (array)[].

`empty()` almost does the job but falls on these mysql decimal values sometimes returned as strings. isset() and is_null() operates differently in PHP 7 and 8. I am missing something like emptyish().

What does not work:

```
if (empty($var)) // Doesn't work for decimal/floats passed as string "0.00"
if ($var == 0) // Leaves a warning if $var is not declared
```

Comment: Use strict comparisons. Always know what data type your values are.

Comment: @JohnConde That's not always convenient. A form may pass numeric values as strings and MySQL PHP drivers can sometimes return int and float as string. Sure one could state a whole switch of variable types and comparisons. But lets be realistic, time is money.

Comment: So do you want to detect 0, an empty string or all possible "empty" values?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to solve here? You can't check with a single line of code for all possible scenarios. You need to have some expectations. If you expect a string, then check if the variable is set and is not an empty string. If you expect an integer then check if the value is set, and is not 0. etc.

Comment: @Dharman it's possible you overcomplicated it a bit. I don't care for the variable type. I just want to make sure if the variable is empty.

Comment: Yes, but what does it mean to be empty? `"0"` is not an empty string, for example.

Comment: You are still overcomplicating things. What can you find in a bank account that has a zero balance? I want to determine if any of the following: (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", (bool)false, null, (int)0, (float)0.00, or (array)[]. Read the question again.

Comment: Without having concrete rules, there is no one-size-fits-all solution. Would you consider `'0be1'` to be empty? It's not empty for me, but according to your rules, it is. If you expect an integer then it is empty. If you expect a non-zero integer then even `0.1` is empty. However, if I expect a string then any non-zero-length string is non-empty for me. This is exactly why we have types. Otherwise, you could simply do `if($var)` and be done with it. I am not overcomplicating things, I am just trying to understand what exactly is your question.

Comment: If all you want is to check against 8 predefined values then you can list them out in an array and use `in_array` to check if they match. e.g. https://3v4l.org/q771M

Comment: Also, I really do not understand the loose comparisons you provided in the question. Why are you checking if it is greater or less than? Why are you not using strict comparison at all? Using loose comparison you are going to run into such confusion, but that is on you. You should try to always use strict comparison.

Comment: A strict comparison doesn't really serve a good purpose in this case. I'm not a fan of blowing up my code when I can have it minimalistic. You should provide your in_array() example as an optional answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This zero/empty condition works the same way in both PHP 7 and 8 versions:

```
if (empty($var) || (is_numeric($var) && (float)$var == 0))
```

It checks if $var is any of the following:
not set, null, (bool)false, (int)0, (float)0.00, (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", or (array)[]

And to substitute empty():

```
  // Checks if variable is not set, null, (bool)false, (int)0, (float)0.00, (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", (array)[], or array with nil nodes
function nil(&$var) { // https://www.dictionary.com/browse/nil
  return (empty($var) || (is_numeric($var) && (float)$var == 0));
}
```

To be used like:

```
if (nil($var)) {
  echo 'The value is either not set, an empty string, empty array, null, or equals zero.';
}
```

It can be expanded to check subnodes for arrays as well:

```
  // Checks if variable is not set, null, (bool)false, (int)0, (float)0.00, (string)"", (string)"0", (string)"0.00", (array)[], or array with nil nodes
  function nil(&$var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
      foreach ($var as $node) {
        if (!nil($node)) return !1;
      }
    }
    return (empty($var) || (is_numeric($var) && (float)$var == 0));
  }
```

Comment: Uhm... you should never compare a float equality, but always inequality.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Care to provide an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)
[gettype](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.gettype.php)

Isset checking on null and not empty value. Via gettype you can avoid type string.

```php
if(isset($var) || gettype($v) !== 'string'){
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: I don't care about the variable type, I just care if it is anything else but empty or zero.

Answer (score 0):

use isset().

```php
<?php
if(isset($var)){
  //$var is set
  if(!$var){
    //$var is 0
  } else if(empty($var)){
    //$var is empty
  } else {
    //code goes here
  }
}else{
  //$var is not set
}
```

Comment: `empty()` after `isset()` is always inappropriate -- it has already been guaranteed that the element is declared.